# How to make custom style UITableViewCell inset from safe area?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-simulator, safearealayoutguide

How can I make a UITableViewCell with custom style inset from the safe area of the device screen when it is part of the view hierarchy `UINavigationController > UIViewController > UIView > UITableView > UITableViewCell`? My UITableViewCell left side is getting cut off by the camera notch.

Setting the iOS 11 `[contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`][1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior?language=objc) and [`insetsContentViewsToSafeArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2921665-insetscontentviewstosafearea?language=objc) methods do not work when I have a combination of both custom layout UITableViewCell (not one of the Basic/Detail view styles) and am using the UITableViewCell in a view that is itself within a UINavigationController. And those values should default to YES.

I've also tried setting [`preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622653-preservessuperviewlayoutmargins?language=objc) which defaults to NO.

**A couple of the behaviors**

1. Setting the view hierarchy as `UIViewController > UIView > UITableView > UITableViewCell. UIViewController` is the entry point of the Storyboard. (below)

   - The custom UITableViewCell is inset from the horizontal safe area correctly like normal.

[image: setup1]

2. Setting the view hierarchy as `UINavigationController > UIViewController > UIView > UITableView > UITableViewCell`. UINavigationController is the entry point of the Storyboard with UIViewController as the root view controller to the navigation controller.

   - Only the UITableView requires `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES` to inset the Basic/Detail style UITableViewCell from the safe area.
3. Setting the view hierarchy as `UINavigationController > UIViewController > UIView > UITableView > UITableViewCell`. UINavigationController is the entry point of the Storyboard with UIViewController as the root view controller to the navigation controller.

   - Unable to inset the default style UITableViewCell from the safe area.
   - In the below screenshot the `UITableView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES` with a custom layout UITableViewCell but the cell fails to properly inset with safe area as seen in the cutoff simulator at the bottom.

[image: setup#3]

- My layout constraints for the custom UITableViewCell are shown below. As seen Interface Builder simulates the correct inset but the actual simulator run does not inset the cell.

[image: custom constraints]

The view hierarchies in #2 and #3 are the same with the only difference being the use of a custom layout UITableViewCell vs the default Basic/Detail style.

I've tried setting `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES` on every view in the hierarchy and it makes not difference for getting the custom UITableViewCell to inset. I made a simple test project [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJJ2f91pgm2QtBjlJMZZXoaPn2nSkOsX/view?usp=sharing) demonstrating the inset issue between default Basic and custom style cells in the described view hierarchy.

I can't be the only one testing a custom UITableViewCell on a landscape iPhone X/11. How can I get the table cell contents to inset correctly from the device safe area? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?